# How to reset the value of a state in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, reset

I want to reset and save the state of the items inside `initialState` to 0 on the click of the button `resetvalues`.

```
const initialState = {
  present_count: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  total_count: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  present: 0,
  total: 0
};

export default class MarkAttendanceScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      subjects: [],
      text: "",
      ...initialState,
    }
  }

  resetvalues = () => { 
    this.setState({ ...initialState });
  };

 ...

};
```

**NOTE:**
The current code is not changing and saving the state of those values.
I used an alert box to check if the function is accessible, that is working fine!
I am using AsyncStorage to save the modified state.

Comment: Try please `this.setState(initialState);`

Comment: Tried. Didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!

```
const defaultState = {
  subjects: [],
  text: "",
  present_count: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  total_count: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  present: 0,
  total: 0
}

export default class MarkAttendanceScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...defaultState,
      refreshing: false,
    }
  }

  resetvalues = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...defaultState,
      subjects: this.state.subjects,
      text: this.state.text
    });
  };
  ...
};
```